# Emails displaying incorrectly - Body shown as attachment

Tags: email, email-server, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I have an issue with our journal mailbox displaying emails in a strange way. We have a mailbox called `archive` that is used to journal/capture all email in and out of the mail server. Our email archive appliance then pulls the emails from this mailbox and archives them.

Recently I've noticed the emails are just showing up with the Sender, Subject, Message-ID and Recipient information in the body and not the actual email content. The email content is attached to the email however and can be downloaded and viewed as a .eml file. At first I thought it was an error on the archive box but when I open the mailbox up in OWA, it displays in the same way. Pic:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhEi6.png)

This has only started happening over the last few days and I don't recall making any changes that may have influenced this.

Is anyone able to shed any light on this issue? This doesn't occur on any other mailboxes when viewed in OWA. Just our archive/journal mailbox and only recently.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The email being attached to the message is the expected behaviour. That is called Envelope Journaling.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb331962(v=exchg.141).aspx

"Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 supports envelope journaling only. "
Therefore what you are seeing with regards to the attachment is what I would expect.

If you have been seeing something else, then that was NOT the correct behaviour. What you have now is.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This confirmation lead me to fix the issue via our archive appliance. I was barking up the wrong tree.